# Remove element from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to delete an element that in this case is an array within another array

```
arr = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']];
tag = ['c','d'];
```

I want to remove tag from arr, and for that I'm trying to do this:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(tag), 1);
```

But I do not know why it does not work, How could I do this?

Comment: Thats because `indexOf` can't find `tag`. Don't think you can use an array as an argument for it.

Comment: `indexOf` uses strict equality. Different arrays are not strictly equal because they're different objects, even if they contain the same elements. You'd need to use a filter and either manually or via a library do an array compare (and decide other things like if order is important etc).

Comment: If tag is equal to ``['c','e']`` it will fail and remove the second element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `[1, 2, 3] != [1, 2, 3]` in javascript. Arrays and object comparisons are not done by the values. This also applies to `indexOf()`.

You need to tell javascript what you mean by equality:

```js
arr = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']];
tag = ['c','d'];

function array_equals(a, b){
    return a.length === b.length && a.every((item,idx) => item === b[idx])
}

console.log(arr.filter(item => !array_equals(item, tag)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check every item in the arrays, because with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), you check the object reference, which is not the same, even with same values.

Assuming the same length of the arrays for checking.

```js
var arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']],
    tag = ['c','d'],
    result = arr.filter(a => !a.every((v, i) => v === tag[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This filters out `['c', 'd']` when `tag = ['c','d', 'e']`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a doble filter. First to separate the arrays and second will be the one comparing each value and will filter out the tag element.

```js
arr = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']];
tag = ['c','d'];


console.log(arr.filter(el=> el.filter((c,i)=> c != tag[i]).length != 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In a lazyer alternative, the arrays can be converted and compared as strings if none of the values contains `,` :

```js
var arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], tag = ['c', 'd'];

console.log( arr.filter(a => a != tag + '') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a filter function which removes number 5 from an array of number arrays:

```js
let winComb = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [3, 6, 9],
  [1, 5, 9],
  [3, 5, 7],
];

for (let i = 0; i < winComb.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    newArr = winComb[i].filter(function (item) {
      return item !== 5;
    });
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}
```